# How do I identify objects with the Java Access Bridge?

Tags: java, c#, java-access-bridge

Is there any method or property for consistently identifying objects using Java Access Bridge?

I tried using AccessibleContextInfo name property. But most of the time this returns an empty string in our client applications (e.g Root Pane, Layered Pane, Panel and EditBox).

Comment: JAB is retuning the Index In Parent from that i generated the Unique number.

Answer (score 0):

Is there keyword instanceof? If yes you can use that to identifing Objects.

```
if(obj instanceof Object) {
  Object newObj = (Object) obj;
  //Do what you need to do...
}
```

Comment: FYI, Object is exist. but JAB is not providing the value of the object.